# How do I get a constant recognized in my mailer file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, constants, mailer

With Rails 5, how do I get a constant recognized in my mailer file?  I have this file,  app/mailers/user_notifier.rb,

```
class UserNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
    ...

  # send notification email to user about the price
  def send_confirmation_email(user_id)
    @user = User.find(user_id)
    mail( :to => @user.email,
    :subject => Constants::EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUBJECT )
  end

end
```

but when it gets to the line, ":subject => Constants::EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUBJECT )" it dies with the error

```
    uninitialized constant Constants::EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUBJECT
```

despite the fact i have the constant defined in my config/initializers/global.rb file

```
module Constants

  # Subject for email confirmations
  EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUBJECT = "Please confirm your email."

end
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Initializers files are parsed only when the application starts. If you're using spring (which is by default and I assume you do) it will use the version of the global.rb initializer that you had when spring started. You will need to restart the web server (rails restart or touch tmp/restart.txt) and if you're using sidekiq or something similar restart sidekiq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to prefix the constant with the module name. The constant will be available in the global scope.

email:

```
def send_confirmation_email(user_id)
 @user = User.find(user_id)
 mail( :to => @user.email,
  :subject => EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUBJECT )
end
```

config/initializers/global.rb

```
EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_SUBJECT = "Please confirm your email."
```

Although, I've got to suggest you use the internationalization in Rails since it's built just for this purpose http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html